# Azure ML Environment build failing - SDKv1

Tags: azure, environment, azure-sdk-python

We have been building ML environments using docker files in Azure workspace using a CI pipeline. It used to work fine until today we tried to rebuild the environment with new conda dependencies.

The build job fails with a weird error, which seems to be a internal bug. Here is the screenshot of the job:

[image]

On looking at logs, we see this:

[image]
[image]

The script above "script.py" is azures's internal script. I believe its missing an `exists_ok=True` in `mkdir(name, mode)`. Thats why it complains that file is already present.

Has someone faced this before, or how can this be handleded.